# Format array where data take from table database

Tags: java, php, mysql, arrays, json

i have this code

```
$Query = mysql_query("Select*from mbulan");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($Query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$items = array($row['id']=>$row['bulan']);
foreach ($items as $key=>$value) {
        echo json_encode(array("$value"));}
}
```

and the output something like this :

```
["January"]["Fabruary"]["Maret"]["April"]["Mei"]["Juni"]
```

but i wan change the output like :

```
["January","February","Maret","April","Mei","Juni"]
```

what should i do for the code and where is the code must be change it ?

Comment: you each item individually convert to json, and you want to convert the entire array

Comment: What does Java actually have to do with this problem? (You have tagged JAVA)?

Comment: @Xatenev..am using a autocomplete textbox where in 1 form have more than 2 textbox input.of all there is only one that I think can be used (Jquery autocomplete).the code before is take an .js file where the var like an array 
ex : var months =["","","",""] var days=["","",""] etc,at least there are some function java that leads to the file..but that's just an array var in .js n i think if i can change it with data from database would be more flexible..so i change the .js file in to .js.php file and used as a replacement without removing variables and the function still working verry well

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code ..

```
$Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mbulan");
$item = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($Query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $items[] = $row['bulan'];
}

echo json_encode($items);
```

Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: thank for spirit ^^ 
I am new in java,PHP language and I am very interested to learn this

Answer (score 0):

json_encode turns an entire array into one json string,  so just get all of you months into one array and output it

```
$Query = mysql_query("Select bulan from mbulan");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($Query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
     $bulan[] = $row['bulan'];
}

echo json_encode($bulan)
```

You should also use pdo for better results, and for more long-term support.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php